# Is it possible to get output of all same time running sub-processes in Bash

Tags: bash, subprocess

I have a bash code like this.

```
while <some_condition>
do
    some_script &
done
```

My purpose is that to get all outputs of some_script code and assign a variable. I tried to write

```
out=`some_script &`
```

but this time some_script codes did not run at same time. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect the background commands to temp files, then `wait` for them to finish and gather the ouput back to the variable:

```
while <some_condition>
do
    temp=$(mktemp)
    temps=$temps" $temp"
    some_script > $temp &
done
wait
output=$(cat $temps)
rm $temps
```

Comment: The bash man page suggests the faster equivalent `$( < $temps)`.

Comment: You can also eliminate the temp file by wrapping the entire `while`/`wait` combo in the command substitution: `output=$( while ...; do some_script &; done; wait)`

Comment: @chepner: `$(< file)` can only be used for a single file. Wrapping the whole loop into `$()` can make the ouput lines interleaved, which you might not want.

Comment: You're right; I missed that you were passing a list of file names to `cat` in a single variable. My first read of the question led me to think the output order didn't matter, but now I suspect that is wrong as well. If you don't mind, I'll leave my comments here as related-but-irrelevant tips.